# SQL Server deadlock - with S and IX lock mode

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

Recently we encountered deadlock issues when more users using the system, below is the log details, appreciate if someone can provide guides on how to resolve this:

How `S` or `IX` lock mode causing the deadlock?

I am thinking probably to improve the query time for the select statement, so that it could release the lock sooner.

```
<TextData>
  <deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process6956d8">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process6956d8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 8:1:6923" waittime="1840" ownerId="67336413" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-07-08T16:22:34.897" XDES="0x124272700" lockMode="S" schedulerid="2" kpid="5472" status="suspended" spid="64" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" transcount="1" lastbatchstarted="2013-07-08T16:22:34.900" lastbatchcompleted="2013-07-08T16:22:34.900" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver" hostname="VIRTIPH-MAS001" hostpid="0" loginname="prtcmt_user" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="67336413" currentdb="8" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x02000000ec69351d69911b1227018da1e1e67e60256cd8be">
select top 290 workplan0_.id as id112_, workplan0_.request_mode as request2_112_, workplan0_.cmt_status_id as cmt3_112_, workplan0_.requestType_rd_id as requestT4_112_, workplan0_.requested_dt as requested5_112_, workplan0_.generic_desc as generic6_112_, workplan0_.brand_desc as brand7_112_, workplan0_.strength as strength112_, workplan0_.prod_form_name as prod9_112_, workplan0_.pack_desc as pack10_112_, workplan0_.inv_uom_desc as inv11_112_, workplan0_.pack_uom_desc as pack12_112_, workplan0_.requestType_name as request13_112_, workplan0_.site_name as site14_112_, workplan0_.priority as priority112_, workplan0_.source as source112_, workplan0_.cmt_status_code as cmt17_112_, workplan0_.prev_cmt_status_code as prev18_112_, workplan0_.swmd_prod_id as swmd19_112_, workplan0_.hppl_lookslike_id as hppl20_112_, workplan0_.amt_id as amt21_112_, workplan0_.locked_dt as locked22_112_ from ipharm_workPlanView workplan0_ where workplan0_.requestType_rd_id=6 and workplan0_.cmt_status_id=33 order by workplan0_.generic_des     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
select top 290 workplan0_.id as id112_, workplan0_.request_mode as request2_112_, workplan0_.cmt_status_id as cmt3_112_, workplan0_.requestType_rd_id as requestT4_112_, workplan0_.requested_dt as requested5_112_, workplan0_.generic_desc as generic6_112_, workplan0_.brand_desc as brand7_112_, workplan0_.strength as strength112_, workplan0_.prod_form_name as prod9_112_, workplan0_.pack_desc as pack10_112_, workplan0_.inv_uom_desc as inv11_112_, workplan0_.pack_uom_desc as pack12_112_, workplan0_.requestType_name as request13_112_, workplan0_.site_name as site14_112_, workplan0_.priority as priority112_, workplan0_.source as source112_, workplan0_.cmt_status_code as cmt17_112_, workplan0_.prev_cmt_status_code as prev18_112_, workplan0_.swmd_prod_id as swmd19_112_, workplan0_.hppl_lookslike_id as hppl20_112_, workplan0_.amt_id as amt21_112_, workplan0_.locked_dt as locked22_112_ from ipharm_workPlanView workplan0_ where workplan0_.requestType_rd_id=6 and workplan0_.cmt_status_id=33 order by workplan0_.generic_de    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="processc7c5ec58" taskpriority="0" logused="9904" waitresource="PAGE: 8:1:6922" waittime="936" ownerId="67336189" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-07-08T16:22:33.930" XDES="0x123635380" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="1" kpid="5232" status="suspended" spid="61" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" transcount="2" lastbatchstarted="2013-07-08T16:22:35.930" lastbatchcompleted="2013-07-08T16:22:35.927" clientapp="Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver" hostname="VIRTIPH-MAS001" hostpid="0" loginname="prtcmt_user" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="67336189" currentdb="8" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="890" sqlhandle="0x02000000a89737254800790c60bb4d0fa72b9640012d8592">
update requestedProduct set version=@P0, create_user=@P1, create_dt=@P2, last_update_user=@P3, last_update_dt=@P4, requested_by=@P5, requested_dt=@P6, requested_byName=@P7, requested_byTitle=@P8, status_id=@P9, status_by=@P10, status_date=@P11, cmt_status_id=@P12, prev_cmt_status_id=@P13, prod_id=@P14, source_prod_id=@P15, hppl_lookslike_id=@P16, amt_id=@P17, fred_code=@P18, source=@P19, swmd_prod_id=@P20, locked_dt=@P21, locked_by=@P22, request_mode=@P23, original_request_mode=@P24, site_rd_id=@P25, priority_rd_id=@P26, submitted_priority_rd_id=@P27, requestType_rd_id=@P28, comment=@P29 where id=@P30 and version=@P31     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 int,@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 datetime,@P3 nvarchar(4000),@P4 datetime,@P5 bigint,@P6 datetime,@P7 nvarchar(4000),@P8 nvarchar(4000),@P9 bigint,@P10 bigint,@P11 datetime,@P12 bigint,@P13 bigint,@P14 int,@P15 int,@P16 nvarchar(4000),@P17 nvarchar(4000),@P18 nvarchar(4000),@P19 nvarchar(4000),@P20 varchar(8000),@P21 datetime,@P22 bigint,@P23 int,@P24 int,@P25 bigint,@P26 bigint,@P27 bigint,@P28 bigint,@P29 varchar(8000),@P30 bigint,@P31 int)update requestedProduct set version=@P0, create_user=@P1, create_dt=@P2, last_update_user=@P3, last_update_dt=@P4, requested_by=@P5, requested_dt=@P6, requested_byName=@P7, requested_byTitle=@P8, status_id=@P9, status_by=@P10, status_date=@P11, cmt_status_id=@P12, prev_cmt_status_id=@P13, prod_id=@P14, source_prod_id=@P15, hppl_lookslike_id=@P16, amt_id=@P17, fred_code=@P18, source=@P19, swmd_prod_id=@P20, locked_dt=@P21, locked_by=@P22, request_mode=@P23, original_request_mode=@P24, site_rd_id=@P25, priority_rd_id=@P26, submitted_priority_rd_id=@P27, requestType_r    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="6923" dbid="8" objectname="MYDB.dbo.requestedProduct" id="lockedec4680" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594227261440">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processc7c5ec58" mode="IX" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process6956d8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="6922" dbid="8" objectname="MYDB.dbo.requestedProduct" id="lockfa82e880" mode="SIU" associatedObjectId="72057594227261440">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process6956d8" mode="S" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processc7c5ec58" mode="IX" requestType="convert" />
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
</TextData>)
```